# QML Keys.onEnterPressed issue

Tags: qt, event-handling, qml, qt-quick

I have a QtQuick project for Desktop. It is very simple:

```
// import QtQuick 1.0 // to target S60 5th Edition or Maemo 5
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Grid
    {
        id: xGrid
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        columns: 2
        spacing: 1

        Rectangle
        {
            height: parent.height
            width: 10
            color: "#ff0000"
            Text {
                id: xText
                text: qsTr("t\na\ns")
            }
        }
        TextEdit
        {
            id: xTextEdit
            height: parent.height
            width: 350
            Keys.onEnterPressed: {
                console.log(event.key)
                xText.text = (qsTr("A"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code does not run like I want.  The `Keys.onEnterPressed` seem never be captured, so I try `Keys.onPressed` it work but not sure why when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the `even.key` returns 16777220.

Any one get this issue? How can I solve it?
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Do you mean that when you press the "Enter" key on the numeric pad (key code 16777221), it is recognized as the "Return" key (16777220) ?

Comment: Yes, and I think that why my code never trigger the *Keys.onEnterPressed*!

Comment: can you try onReturnPressed handler?

Comment: @Kunal : One every pc out there can I use onReturnPressed instead of onEnterPressed?

Comment: Classic Enter key is named a "Return" and what they called "Enter" is Enter form NumPad

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I got the same problem with a `TextInput` item. I tried

- `onPressed`
- `onEnterPressed`
- `onReturnPressed`

Only the latter one worked (`onReturnPressed`). I guess, the underlying implementation of the `TextInput` captures the 'Enter' key so it doesn't get processed by the `onPressed` signal in a regular way.

By the way: the key code is correct. It's an abstraction on the platform specific key codes.

Comment: > I guess, the underlying implementation of the TextInput captures the 'Enter' key so it doesn't get processed by the onPressed signal in a regular way. 

Your code should be processed first by default. See [Keys.priority](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keys.html#priority-prop)

Comment: @drzymala Keys.onEnterPressed should be called when you press on the enter key *from the numeric keypad* on the right side of the keyboard. That's one this one is for.

Answer (score 6):

A better way to handle users entering a text value is to use TextInput.onAccepted

Here's an example:

```
TextInput {
    onAccepted: processText()
}
```

When the user presses Enter, the processText() method will be called.
This approach is simpler and should improve cross-platform portability.

Answer (score 4):

```
TextArea {
id: messageField
Layout.fillWidth: true
placeholderText: qsTr("Message")
wrapMode: TextArea.Wrap
inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText

function _onEnterPressed(event)
{
    if ((event.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier))
    {
        sendMessage()
    }
    else
    {
        event.accepted = false;
    }
}

Keys.onReturnPressed: { _onEnterPressed(event) }
Keys.onEnterPressed: { _onEnterPressed(event) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use onReturnPressed as well. Otherwise you can also check the key value in onPressed() and react there. onReturn/EnterPressed are just convenience functions.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially relevant context taken from the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keys.html#key-handling-priorities):

> [...] the order of key event
>   processing is:
>
> 1. Items specified in forwardTo
> 2. specific key handlers, e.g. onReturnPressed
> 3. onPressed, onReleased handlers
> 4. Item specific key handling, e.g. TextInput key handling
> 5. parent item